# php file extensions: security issue?

Tags: php, security

I'm a self-taught coder and am getting into php, so please excuse me if this is a basic issue/question.

I've been putting together small sites using php and using php file extensions, ie. index.php. But I've recently been told that 'php' in the page address is not good for security.

Can someone please briefly explain why this might be the case and what I *should* be doing?

MTIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not *really* important, it just tells someone browsing the site that your app is written in PHP and that helps an attacker because they then have an idea of what to attack.

If you want to conceal it, you can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to rewrite requests that don't have a .php extension to the target PHP script.  If you're going to do this, you should also turn off `expose_php` in the php.ini.

Note that this doesn't really make your app more secure, it just makes it that little bit harder for an attacker to figure things out.

Comment: The app could be written in anything. Just because the URI ends in `.php`, doesn't mean a thing. It could map to Java, Ruby, C++, Perl, anything.

Comment: @Phil, you're quite right; if you wanted to lead potential attackers astray you could name them something else like `.asp` and add a handler that calls the PHP engine on `.asp` files.

Comment: When there are many other vectors such as SQL injection, I think it's less important what language the application is in than how secure the actual coding and server is.

Comment: Yeah, definitely agree.  I don't go out of my way to hide the extensions, although I use `mod_rewrite` to give nice URLs anyway, which ends up hiding the extension of my scripts, but that's a side effect rather than the main intention.

Answer (score 1):

Obfuscating what technology you're using is no substitute for securing your application and its infrastructure.  Hiding the PHP file extension should be one detailed item in a list of many steps you should take to secure your code and server.

Entire books are written on PHP security topics.  Here's a good one to start with:

[http://www.amazon.com/Essential-PHP-Security-Chris-Shiflett/dp/059600656X/ref=pd_sim_b_2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/059600656X)

Answer (score 1):

By having the .php in the page name, you are announcing to the world that your site runs on PHP.  Anyone who is interested in attacking your site would then not have to spend extra time and energy figuring out what you running.

However, this is not a MAJOR problem.  Someone who is hell-bent on attacking you will figure it out soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason it may be *wrong* from security perspective is that it actually tells everyone visiting the site, what technology (which scripting language) has been used to build the site. Everything else results from the higher possibility that the user knows it is PHP (eg. attacker may try to exploit some common mistakes made by some PHP coders).

However, you may easily change the extension into eg. `.asp` by using `mod_rewrite` ([see more](http://tinyurl.com/dnzodh)).